# Adding multiple children and subchildren to existing XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am running a query against the Active Directory to get a list of managers and direct reports. I was writing the output to a listbox but I need to create an XML file from this info to use in a different application.
My XML should look like this...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <org_chart>
      <employees>
        <manager managerID="A999999" managerName="Smith">
          <employee e_id="A111111" lastname="Adams" firstname="Alex" />
          <employee e_id="A111112" lastname="Burns" firstname="Bonnie" />
          <employee e_id="A111113" lastname="Cole" firstname="Cory" />
        </manager>
        <manager managerID="A888888" managerName="Jones" />
          <employee e_id="A222222" lastname="Darnell" firstname="Danny" />
          <employee e_id="A222223" lastname="Earnest" firstname="Earl" />
      </employees>
    </org_chart>
```

But instead it looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<org_chart>
  <employees>
    <manager managerID="A999999" managerName="Smith">
      <employee e_id="A111111" lastname="Adams" firstname="Alex" />
      <employee e_id="A111112" lastname="Burns" firstname="Bonnie" />
      <employee e_id="A111113" lastname="Cole" firstname="Cory" />
      <employee e_id="A222222" lastname="Darnell" firstname="Danny" />
      <employee e_id="A222223" lastname="Earnest" firstname="Earl" />
    </manager>
    <manager managerID="A888888" managerName="Jones" />
  </employees>
</org_chart>
```

I need it to loop though all managers and creates child elements for the direct reports but it seems to be putting all direct reports into the first manager node.
So I guess I need to know how to get the direct reports for the second manager into the correct node.
My latest code looks like this:

```
 XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(directReportsFile);
                XElement xm = new XElement("manager");
                xm.SetAttributeValue("managerID", mID);
                xm.SetAttributeValue("managerName", managerName);
                doc1.Element("org_chart").Element("employees").Add(xm);
                doc1.Save(directReportsFile);

                DirectoryEntry de2 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://***");
                DirectorySearcher ds2 = new DirectorySearcher(de2);
                ds2.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + mID + "))";
                ds2.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                SearchResult rs2 =ds2.FindOne();
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(directReportsFile);
                
                foreach (string objProperty2 in rs2.Properties["DirectReports"])  //for each direct report of the manager...
                {
                    string employee = objProperty2.ToString();
                    string[] setp2 = new string[1];
                    setp2[0] = "OU";
                    employee = employee.Split(setp2, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                    employee = employee.Replace("CN=", "");
                    employee = employee.TrimEnd(',');
                    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
                    {
                        using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, employee))
                        {
                            if (user != null)
                            {
               
                                XElement xe = new XElement("employee");
                                xe.SetAttributeValue("e_id", employee);
                                xe.SetAttributeValue("lastname", user.Surname);
                                xe.SetAttributeValue("firstname", user.GivenName);
                                doc.Element("org_chart").Element("employees").Element("manager").Add(xe);
                                doc.Save(directReportsFile);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This `doc.Element("org_chart").Element("employees").Element("manager")` grabs the first `manager` element. You want to grab the *correct* `manager` element. You can filter it e.g. `Elements("manager").Single(x => (string)x.Attribute("managerID") == ???)`, but I'm not sure we have enough information to know what to filter it by.

Comment: As an aside, I'd suggest you *don't* want to save your document on every loop iteration. Or save it and re-load at the start. Just load it once at the start and save it once at the end?

Comment: When debugging what do you get in rs2.Properties["DirectReports"] for the first manager?

Comment: The line of code I neglected to post shows where I get the manager ID, passing it to a variable.  So I should be able to use that as the filter, right? Seems obvious but i haven't figured out how to do it

Comment: In fact, you create the `manager` element at the start. If you remove the part where you re-load the document as `doc` (it's already loaded as `doc1`), you can just add the `employee` element to `xm` - no need to find it, you have it.

Comment: Thanks, Charles! I knew what it was NOT doing but I couldn't see it.  I added the employee element to the manager and then it all lined up as needed.

XElement xe = new XElement("employee");
...
xm.Add(xe);